# xQuery IF condition does not work properly

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am trying this condition, but it always exits through else way, could you help me? thanks

```
if ( $orderLine[osm:ProductSpecification/text()="X"] and osm:ExtensibleAttributes[osm:Name = "Y" or osm:Name = "Z"] and osm:NewValue/text() = "A" )
            then
                 <AccessType>X</AccessType>
            else
                 <AccessType>{$attribute/osm:NewValue/text()}</AccessType>
            )
```

Comment: Clearly there's no way we can help you debug this without seeing the source document, or knowing what $orderLine contains. We're not magicians.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem changing the filter scope:

```
if ( $orderLine[osm:ProductSpecification/text()="X" and osm:ExtensibleAttributes[osm:Name = "Y" or osm:Name = "Z"] and osm:NewValue/text() = "A" ]])
            then
                 <AccessType>X</AccessType>
            else
                 <AccessType>{$attribute/osm:NewValue/text()}</AccessType>
            )
```

Comment: In some cases, when the document is known or is constrained by a schema, it is known that both sides of the equality test are single items. It is then more efficient to use `eq` (value comparison) than `=` (general comparison), as the latter involves a double existential quantification ("there exists two items that match"). A smart engine will optimize automatically, but it can only do so to the extent of what information it has on the input.